# "Create a Salesforce DX Project" - getting message WARNING: The following metadata isn’t in your org

Tags: metadata, salesforcedx-cli, git

In the "Develop an App with Salesforce CLI and Source Control" Trailhead I think I'm following the instructions to the letter, but at the "Create a Salesforce DX Project" when I attempt to retrieve the DreamHouse app’s metadata I keep getting this error message:

---

=== WARNING: The following metadata isn’t in your org. If it’s not new, someone deleted it from the org.

Entity of type 'ApexClass' named 'DreamHouseSampleDataControllerTest' cannot be found

Entity of type 'ContentAsset' named 'DreamHouseLogo' cannot be found

Entity of type 'PermissionSet' named 'DreamHouse' cannot be found

Please explain any answers to me like I'm 5 years old, because I am very new to source control. Thanks.

Comment: can you add your vscode project structure picture, it'll give more idea

Comment: Sure, but can you give me more info about what exactly you're asking for-- do you mean  the directory hierarchy that appears in the left side panel?

Comment: can you tell us what command you used for retrieve the metadata? i knew `sfdx force:source:retrieve` command  unable to pull some of components like `ContentAsset` and `Audiences`

Comment: First the trailhead had me create a package.xml file in my local directory, then run this command--
sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest assets/package.xml --targetusername DevHub --wait 10

Answer (score 0):

This warning simply means you haven't installed the Dreamhouse code yet. There is an unmanaged package for you to install, or you can come the Dreamhouse code directly from the github repository. This should have been part of a [previous module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_dev_basics/platform_dev_basics_intro) on installing code.

Comment: I did install the Dreamhouse package though. I've run through the trailhead lessons 3 times and I keep getting the same error. The metadata retrieval works on a couple dozen entities but fails on the three I listed.